# Defining a method to determine the local variable name of an associated instance

Tags: javascript

Let’s say I have this function:

```
function myFunction(x,y,z) {
   this.var1 = x*y;
   this.var2 = "someting else";
};

myFunction.prototype.whatismyname = function() {
 // return my name here.
};

var varName = new myFunction(10,99,7);
```

I would like to call `varName.whatismyname();` and have it return the text 
`"varName"`, or whatever the name of the declared variable is. That is, can I have a method that will give me the name used to declare an instance variable?

Comment: This isn’t really possible, maybe because this shouldn’t be necessary, ever.

Comment: In the title it says “within the function”, in the question you declare it outside the function. Which is it?!

Comment: why is the question unclear? I have a function, which  once its called it write a bit of code using document.body.innerHTML,+="...."
in the content I write I want to reference the name of the variable used to declare the function.... it helps simplify a complex process. so, maybe not necessary.. but very helpful to be able to do this.

Comment: sorry for the terrible spelling, just noticed it now. 
Xufos.. the variable is declare outside.. but you reference the declared name from inside.

Comment: @SergioFernandez When you're typing a comment, there's automatic name completion after '@'.

Comment: yes, I know j08691.. how can I edit the title, when I write fast, sometimes, that happens... should have checked the spelling.

Comment: Click the [edit] link under the question.

Comment: You can't get the name of a variable that was used to call a function. Functions are called by value, nothing about the variable is passed along. There might not even be a variable, it could be `someotherFunction().whatismyname()`.

Comment: No, this is not possible. Variables names are not accessible from JavaScript in any way short of something insane like hooking into your own environment's debugger.

Comment: @Barmar... OK that sucks, it could be very useful a feature to reference the name, and if there is no variable name ... then when you try to get the name you could get maybe '()' or a empty string back ''.
well, thanks for who ever fixed the title of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't practically possible. Local variable names are not preserved in any semantic way in JavaScript; the language has no reflection capabilities that would let you retrieve them. It might be hypothetically possible to have a program in the right environment connect to its own debugger port to determine a local variable name, but that would extremely complicated and slow.

But as a fun exercise, here's a function which will work *for the specific example you've provided*. **PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS FUNCTION IN REAL CODE.** This code checks the name of your class (`this.constructor.name`), and then searches up the call stack for any parent functions containing `X = new NAME`, and returns the first `X` it finds. This approach is extremely crude and unreliable, relies on the super-deprecated `.caller` property, will probably hurt your application performance, won't work in `strict` mode, and your coworkers will give you dirty looks.

```js
function myFunction(x,y,z) {
  this.var1 = x*y;
  this.var2 = "someting else";
};

myFunction.prototype.whatismyname = function() {
  // Get the name of this class's constructor.
  var name = this.constructor.name;

  // Start by searching in the function calling this method.
  var caller = arguments.callee.caller;  
 
  var match = null;

  // Search up the call stack until we find a match or give up.
  while (!match && caller) {
    // Get the source code of this function on the stack.
    var code = caller.toString();

    // Search the source code for X = new NAME.
    var match = new RegExp('\\W(\\w+)\\s*=\\s*new\\s+' + name).exec(code);

    // Move up the stack.
    caller = caller.caller;
  }

  // Return the first match.
  return match && match[1] || undefined;
};

function main() {
  var varName = new myFunction(10,99,7);
  other(varName);
}

function other(myObj) {
  console.log(myObj.whatismyname()); // "varName"
}

main();
```

It "works"! Sort-of. In this case. Don't do it.

Comment: @ Jeremy Banks. yes it works, this is what I am looking for, but I have read, all the comments which discourage us to use this method.... I'll see if their is an alternative to arguments.callee.caller.... since this way it reduces a complex bit of code to a single line.

Comment: well it works for Firefox,chrome, but not IE.. under vista... have not tried it under mobile... but its a good step towards what I wanted.